# Ember TransitionTo with queryParams not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember and I'm trying to use transitionTo with queryParams but I can't get it to work I tried a lot of the solution but I can't find out what is wrong with my code. here the code for the two routes I'm to transition between:

1- index.js:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 setupController: function(controller, model) {
 this._super(controller, model);
 controller.set("model", model);
 },
 model() {
  return {
   searchQuery: ""
  };
 },
 actions: {
  search() {
   const query = this.controller.get("model.searchQuery");
   this.transitionTo("/search-results", {
     queryParams: {
       q: query
     }
   });
  }
 }
});
```

2-search-results.js:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
 model() {
  return {
   fieldsInput: []
  };
 },
 setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this._super(controller, model);
  controller.set("model", model);
 }
});
```

I don't know if anything else should be added. I tried setting queryParams on the controller but it didn't work either. also, I tried adding

```
  queryParams: {
   q: ""
  },
```

to the search results route but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you give url for `transitionTo` method so you need to provide full URL by constructing including queryParams. This will work

```
this.transitionTo(`/search-results?q=${query}`);
```

As you mentioned in comment, you were missing to specify queryParams property in route.

Comment: thank you for the reply. but I tried this and it didn't work either.  it just goes to the route without the query params

Comment: There can be many reason for not working. but I mentioned one critical part in my answer. that's true and it will work. have a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/4b358521437ddbf62be17af55e7b27ce?openFiles=routes.application.js%2C&route=%2Fsearch-results%3Fq%3DchangedValue). if you prepare not working twiddle then it will be easy to solve

Comment: thank you :). the twiddle gave me the missing piece. it was adding the queryParms object on the route. please add update your answer to mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 0):

In "search-results.js", you need to access(tell your model) about the param you passed into the file from index.js, so in search-results.js, your model should look a little like this:

```
model(param) {
   return {
    fieldsInput: [] 
   };
},
```

If you look where you've defined "fieldsInput" above, you're going to want to do some sort of Ember-Data lookup (*if you are not familiar with it, then watch a youtube video or two, it'll help a lot going forward*), to make use of the "queryParam" you passed from index.js.

(Hint: "`return this.store.findRecord(someObject, param.someProperty)`" is probably what you'll want to use)

Also, if you look in the line just under where you've written "`this.transitionTo`", you've a typo in your spelling of "queryParams".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. but @kumkanillam twiddle gave me the missing piece.